# Faulhaber's Formula to evaluate series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

$$S = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k^{99}}{n^{100}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^{100}} \cdot \overbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{99}}^{\text{I}}$$

$$I = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{99} = \frac{1}{99} \cdot \sum_{j=0}^{99} (-1)^j \binom{100}{j} B_j n^{100 - j}$$

But that seems AWFULLY, difficult?
What can be done?

Comment: When dividing $I$ by $n^{100}$, only one term ($j=0$) of the sum survives, since the limit of the other terms when divided by $n^{100}$ is zero.

Comment: How can you bring the limit inside the sum? Can you show uniform convergence?

Comment: Uniform convergence of what? This is just a sum (with a fixed number of terms), not a series of functions.

Comment: I see, it becomes: $$I = \frac{1}{99} \cdot \sum_{j=0}^{99} (-1)^j \binom{100}{j} B_j n^{-j}$$ What did you mean? I got something different?

Comment: This is a Riemann sum.

Comment: I knew that before @Lucian.

Comment: If you know that it is a Riemann sum, why don't use that fact? 
Even if you don't want to use this fact explicitly, for function monotonic over $[0,1]$,
it is trivial to bound the error between the sum and the integral...

$$\left|\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) - \int_0^1 f(x) dx \right| \le \frac1n |f(0)-f(1)|$$

Comment: I knew this before, I was EXPLORING, a different method. @achillehui.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1^{k}+2^{k}+...+n^{k}}{n^{k+1}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1520523/evaluate-lim-n-to-infty-frac1k2k-nknk1)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding Lucien's comment:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k^{99}}{n^{100}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\Bigl(\frac{k}{n}\Bigr)^{99}=\int_0^1x^{99}\,dx.
$$

Answer (score 1):

One doesn't need the full detail of Faulhaber's formula. The relevant fact is that $f_j(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n k^j$ is a polynomial in $n$ with leading coefficient $\dfrac{1}{j+1}$ and degree $j+1$. You can prove this by induction. Hence writing $f_j(n)=\dfrac{1}{j+1} n^{j+1}+O(n^j)$ gives that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_j(n)n^{-(j+1)}=\dfrac{1}{j+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

By Faulhaber,
$$S_n=\frac1{100}+o(\frac1n).$$

Answer (score 0):

Or via Cesaro-Stolz, the discrete version of l'Hopital:
$$
\lim\frac{a_1+...+a_n}{b_1+...+b_n}=\lim \frac{a_n}{b_n}
$$
under suitable assumptions, essentially that the second limit exists. Here
$$
\lim \frac{1+2^{99}+...+n^{99}}{n^{100}}=\lim\frac{n^{99}}{n^{100}-(n-1)^{100}}=\frac1{100}
$$